# Disable minification and uglify in react-native release build for android

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have properly working in development environment `react-native` application. I wanted to test it's performance and released a build, which crashes after the launch.

```
01-09 20:16:13.644 23215 23251 E ReactNativeJS: Object type 't' not found in schema.

01-09 20:16:13.648 23215 23251 E ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

I couldn't determine the cause of crashing because of minification and uglify of the sources. Could you, please, help me with disabling it, because I already spent plenty of hours on it.

**react-native version: 0.49.5**

Comment: You can try integrating Sentry into your app. With the source maps, you see symbolicated errors in Sentry instead of minified code.

Answer (score 6):

putting --minify=false in extraPackagerArgs in android/app/build.gradle should do the job.

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    extraPackagerArgs: [ '--minify=false' ],
];
```

Comment: Also it mentions in the gradlew docs to use  bundleInRelease: false

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the use of the CLI tool, [Haul](https://github.com/callstack/haul)

`Haul bundle --minify false` should do the trick, if not, `Haul` provides other commands as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do it by configuring metro?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first test your app by unchecking dev mode on your in app developer menu.

i had the same problem and it took me some time to figure out.

i disabled the dev mode so it generates the JS bundle same like release bundle and i found the problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone got to here this might help:

`node_modules/.bin/haul bundle --dev=false --config=node_modules/react-native-bundle-visualizer/src/webpack.haul.js`

you can know more doing:

`node_modules/.bin/haul bundle --help`